# Intercept wxListCtrl scroll events

Tags: wxwidgets

I'm using wxWidgets 2.8 on a Linux box.

I'd like to get notifications of scroll events from `wxListCtrl` (or `wxListView`). Basically I want to be notified when someone uses the scrollbars.

I tried with `EVT_SCROLLWIN` and `EVT_SCROLL` without success.

Can someone provide me some sample code?

Unfortunately I cannot find any documentation/sample about this topic. Any pointer?

I need to intercept this event because I'm using a `wxListView` under MOTIF (sic) and when I scroll the list, the new items are not redrawn (basically I see the list empty until I click an item). So, my hack would be to call `wxWindow::Redraw()` after a scroll.
Any alternative solution to my original problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't get scroll events for what can be (even if it is not in wxGTK, actually) a native control, this is just not something that wxWidgets guarantees because it is very difficult (and maybe impossible) to implement in general.

Sorry.

Comment: I see. So is there no way I can know when the user "scrolls" a wxListrCtrl / wxListView?